# How am I suppose to get the width and height of a Frame in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In my python code, I am trying to make the width of my button the same as the width of the Frame it is in. The Frame's width changes when the window is resized. I tried `Widget['width']` and `Widget.winfo_width()` but both of them give me errors.
My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('750x500')
root.minsize(750, 500)


# Frames
Screen = Frame(root, height=500, width=500, bg='pink').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', rowspan=4)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
Buttons = Frame(root, height=500, width=100, bg="blue").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew', rowspan=4, columnspan=2)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

# Buttons
UpgradeBtn = Button(Buttons, text="Upgrades")
UpgradeBtn.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
WallBreakBtn = Button(Buttons, text="Wall Breaking")
WallBreakBtn.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Could you help me?

Comment: I also had ```from tkinter import *``` in the first line of the code btw

Comment: that is bad practice, but just so you know you can [edit] your question to change information there

Comment: You can configure the button to grow without having to get the width. Are you aware of that?

Answer (score 0):

The `.grid` method returns `None` so `Screen` and `Buttons` in your original code were both `None`, not widgets.  Running `.grid` in a second statement means `Screen` or `Buttons` will have the `winfo_XXX` methods.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.geometry('750x500')
root.minsize(750, 500)
# Frames
Screen = Frame(root, height=500, width=500, bg='pink')
Screen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', rowspan=4) # Change
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
Buttons = Frame(root, height=500, width=100, bg="blue")
Buttons.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew', rowspan=4, columnspan=2) # Change
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

# New function
def on_upgrade():
    print(Screen.winfo_width(), Screen.winfo_height())

# Buttons
UpgradeBtn = Button(Buttons, text=" w x h ", command = on_upgrade ) # Change
UpgradeBtn.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
WallBreakBtn = Button(Buttons, text="Wall Breaking")
WallBreakBtn.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

This prints the width and height of Screen to the console.